# Why do I sometimes see systemd status messages despite booting with `quiet`?

Tags: systemd

Debian defaults to `quiet` on the kernel command line (at least installed from the live media I've been using.  Which was possibly a bad idea).

systemd responds to `quiet`, by not printing the standard messages when it starts each service.

So, why do I see systemd status messages when I shut down?

This is on Debian Stretch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man systemd`

> systemd.show_status
>
> Takes a boolean argument or the constant `auto`. Can be also
>              specified without an argument, with the same effect as a positive
>              boolean. If enabled, the systemd manager (PID 1) shows terse
>              service status updates on the console during bootup.  `auto` behaves
>              like false until a unit fails or there is a significant delay in
>              boot. Defaults to enabled, unless quiet is passed as kernel command
>              line option, in which case it defaults to `auto`.

---

When a unit fails, systemd enables status messages despite the `quiet` option.

If the `quiet` option has been passed but was overridden by such a condition, the status messages are re-disabled when the system has finished booting (even if only to emergency mode).

Currently, systemd only ever prints status messages during the initial startup, and during shutdown.  However a unit failure can cause the `quiet` option to be overridden during shutdown, even if the unit failure occurred before the shutdown was initiated.

A second case where `quiet` is overidden is when a unit is taking a while, and systemd prints an animation showing how long the unit is allowed before it times out.

---

The two different override cases can be found in the source code, by looking for `manager_flip_auto_status(m, true)`.

- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/41dfa61d35c51a584437481d20541d5c3ccfa93d/src/core/manager.c#L200
- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/41dfa61d35c51a584437481d20541d5c3ccfa93d/src/core/job.c#L734

There is *not* a call to `manager_flip_auto_status(m, false)` when the system shuts down.  At least not in systemd v235-135-g41dfa61d3.

---

For example, I am currently seeing status messages on startup, due to systemd-backlight trying and failing to set a laptop backlight on an asus desktop.   (Probably some strangeness with the platform driver; there are no devices in `/sys/class/backlight` when the system has finished booting, but it seems that systemd finds one during the boot process).

Comment: Which `systemd` man page is this behavior documented in?

Comment: ooh, good call.  The explanation for "quiet" seems misleading to me, but if you follow the reference it makes, there is documentation.

Comment: I don't see the doc mentioning the part about printing status messages during shutdown as well as during startup.  You can use `man -l` to page through the C file if you like tho :-P.  The code is here:  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/41dfa61d35c51a584437481d20541d5c3ccfa93d/src/core/manager.c#L3331

Comment: If interesting documentation is missing, please submit an issue or a pull request: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/  The source docs are in the "man" subdirectory as ".xml" files. They have been responsive in the past when I've submitted documented improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Because `systemd` is working as documented.   A search in `man systemd` for "quiet" reveals that the kernel option only affects boot, not shutdown.

Comment: Huh.  So it does.  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/fec7615c079a5221ac4f9c9415bfccf8bde6edcf/src/core/job.c#L1238 / https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/41dfa61d35c51a584437481d20541d5c3ccfa93d/src/core/manager.c#L3322

Comment: No, I was wrong.  `no_console_output` only concerns disabling console output when services like the emergency shell are also accessing the console.  Confusingly, there is this hack (first link) to override them on shutdown.  But clearing `no_console_output` does not undo the effect of `quiet`; that is a separate field `m->show_status`, which is "flipped" between STATUS_AUTO and STATUS_TEMPORARY.