# How to "unmask" bootlogd.service

Tags: debian, systemd

Upgraded to Debian Stretch and wanted to have a boot log, so I found that I have to install bootlogd service. The problem is that its status is "masked" and when doing:

```
sudo systemctl unmask bootlogd.service
```

no error is displayed, but when afterwards running:

```
sudo systemctl enable bootlogd.service
```

I am getting this error:

```
Synchronizing state of bootlogd.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable bootlogd
Failed to enable unit: Unit file /lib/systemd/system/bootlogd.service is masked.
```

How to enable this service in order to get a boot log.

Comment: Finally it is mentioned that the systemd package includes a mask file for bootlogd.service, I think this pattern is used in several cases e.g. for hostname.service as well, preventing the sysvinit script for bootlogd being run and there is no way to gainsay it https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?att=1;bug=791907;filename=0001-bootlogd-mention-it-won-t-do-anything-under-systemd.patch;msg=54

Comment: A fundamental premise of this question is wrong, making the direct question unanswerable.  [Put down `bootlogd` and step away from van Smoorenburg `rc`.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html)

Comment: @JdeBP I actually think it's answerable! but I don't think we really want to discuss `dpkg-divert`, removing the `quiet` from the boot options, and the implications of making sure not to run `plymouth` :-).

Comment: @JdeBP Anyway, this question is a pretty good example of "this is the goal I have, and here's what I've tried to achieve it" coming from a new user. I'd say the only omission here, is to cite the source for "I found that I have to install bootlogd". I'd appreciate it if we could avoid blankly calling new users fundamentally wrong - i.e. without a constructive suggestion. After they've provided all the information needed to answer the question.

Comment: Yes, I found the info about 'bootlogd.service' in the other post, but it did not have info that with systemd you should use 'journalctl' instead. I thought that most of the people are busy, so I should not write obvious things like “I found it somewhere, but it did not work” and instead just “cut to the chase”.

Comment: @PiotrMartyniuk I think it's fine. I'm trying to say this is a well-asked question. Responses on this site get on my nerves sometimes, and I think [we should keep trying to do better](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/).

Comment: I just wanted to say it was a perfect question and then felt I couldn't :). Linking to your original source is useful sometimes. For example, we only have your summary of what it says :). There might be an important point in the original instructions, which you had misunderstood. The source might also have included an explanation of what bootlogd does - I didn't know anything about it. To some extent this is a judgement call, e.g. I wouldn't tend to explain where I learned `systemctl enable my-service`. It doesn't sound like the link would have made a difference here, so your judgement was ok.

Comment: _I'd appreciate it if we could avoid blankly calling new users fundamentally wrong._  Then don't you do it, as none of the rest of us have.  I called a fundamental premise of the question wrong, making the direct question (which is _How do I enable this service to get a bootlog?_, remember) unanswerable.  Which it is.  It's not possible to enable that service to get a boot log.  It's _you_ that has so far made comments about the user and not the question.

Comment: @JdeBP Why do you think it is *not* possible to dpkg-divert the mask file, remove or disable plymouth which conflicts with bootlogd, enable bootlogd to get a boot log, and remove the "quiet" option from the boot options to get some content in that boot log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to [...] get a boot log.

```
journalctl -b
```

The messages you will see are also copied by rsyslog, to the various log files under /var/log/.

By default, Debian is set up to use rsyslog for persistent logging. Based on this default, `journalctl` is only able to show recent messages, which are stored temporarily by `journald`.

I generally recommend enabling persistent logging for the journal (you can still keep running rsyslog if you like). It's useful to have the search features of `journalctl` available, especially as more software has started logging to the system log. For example, you can ask for the log of the previous boot with `journalctl -b -1`.  You can enable the persistent journal as follows:

```
mkdir -p /var/log/journal
systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal
systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

-- https://gist.github.com/JPvRiel/b7c185833da32631fa6ce65b40836887

### Enabling bootlogd.service will not help you

> `+        echo "(Booted up using systemd which doesn't write logs to system console. Please check 'journalctl -b' instead.)" > /var/log/boot`

-- logs of Debian Bug report [#791907](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=791907), attachment [0001-bootlogd-mention-it-won-t-do-anything-under-systemd.patch](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?att=1;bug=791907;filename=0001-bootlogd-mention-it-won-t-do-anything-under-systemd.patch;msg=54)

The above does not give the full story.  Systemd does not write any messages to the console *in the default configuration of Debian*, where the system is booted with the `quiet` option on the kernel command line.  Also, it will turn on console messages if a service fails to start. I wrote some detail about this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403884/why-do-i-sometimes-see-systemd-status-messages-despite-booting-with-quiet).

---

The systemctl error message/behaviour you encountered might be considered unfortunate. If someone ever remembers to follow up from the patch which was applied

> Note that systemd package will need to drop the mask of bootlogd.service
>   for this to work.

then your systemctl error message will go away, and `/var/log/boot` should be created at boot time, containing only the message quoted earlier :-).  However I would recommend against doing that.  The console redirection feature which `bootlogd` uses, is also wanted to be used by `plymouth`, so there's a conflict.  I don't know what would happen as a result of that conflict.  I would leave `plymouth` alone, because it can be relied on in some cases like prompting for disk encryption passwords.

BTW plymouth should create `/var/log/boot.log`, showing anything that was written to the console during boot.  At least that's the file it uses on Fedora and Ubuntu.  [Apparently it seems it has not been entirely reliable in some versions in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763638/no-more-boot-logging-since-16-04).

BTW the sort of weird built-in mask that generates the error message you saw, is a mechanism which has also been used [to avoid running sysVinit boot scripts which systemd re-implemented internally.](https://askubuntu.com/a/923077)

Comment: `journalctl -b` is fine. I did not know that `bootlogd.service` is not working anymore with the Stretch. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using the default `systemd`, then its `journald` takes over the job. But you still have the option of using another init system, and if you do that, then `bootlogd` would still be needed. Debian's `systemd` configuration includes a "generator" that automatically provides service configurations for any SysVinit-style startup scripts, including `bootlogd`. The masked `systemd.service` exists only to override that generated service, since `bootlogd`is not needed when systemd is used.