# Systemd: remove reboot/shutdown messages

Tags: systemd

```
OS: archlinux
systemd: systemd 239
```

I read this question in arch forum: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=233243

I follow every single step in this guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Silent_boot

I still can't able to have a `slient` boot, each time reboot/shutdown, that message really nonsense at many level and I hate seeing it.

EDIT: I don't have any failed services:

```
systemctl --failed
0 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

Below is the result from `journalctl -b -1 -u init.scope`, no red messages, and I'm no colorblind :).

```
Nov 04 00:54:14 localhost systemd[1]: Requested transaction contradicts existing jobs: Transaction is destructive.
Nov 04 00:54:14 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.socket: Failed to queue service startup job (Maybe the service file is missing or not a non-template unit?): Transaction is destructive.
Nov 04 00:54:14 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.socket: Failed with result 'resources'.
```

Comment: This can happen because one of the units fails. (I think even if a unit fails during boot, the shutdown shows the messages) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403884/why-do-i-sometimes-see-systemd-status-messages-despite-booting-with-quiet/410133#410133 So firstly, do you see any unit failures e.g. if you look at `journalctl -b -1 init.scope` ?

Comment: Alternatively, Fedora uses a boot splash called "plymouth".  This hides the text messages in favour of a simple graphical throbber, it works great in Fedora.  I think it is too slow to start during shutdown, so you still see the messages at shutdown time.  Though, often shutdown is quick so the messages are less annoying then.

Comment: It is not nonsense at any level, in fact.  The kernel _is_, after all, running the power down or restart procedures when it prints the message about powering down/restarting to the console.  It's rather sad to see that in almost a year no-one correctly identified the source of these messages.

Comment: I've just added more details.

Comment: Actually, you have tacked on a completely different second question that isn't about console messages or silencing them.  This WWW site generally works on the _one question per question_ principle.

Comment: sourcejedi suggest that something critical happened to systemd so even silent it echo message, I'm trying to narrow it down, any suggestion? @JdeBP

Comment: I've just added edit2, no failed services at all.

Comment: [Put down the chocolate covered banana and step away from the European currency systems](https://jdebp.uk/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html).  Be clear about what your goal is, and _ask about that_, not about steps that you _think_ are the steps towards it.  Decide whether eliminating _kernel reboot messages not from systemd on the console_ is the goal, or determining the cause of _service failure messages in your system journal not from reboot/shutdown_ is the goal, or indeed something else entirely is the actual goal.  Then _make that the single question_.

Comment: Sorry, I gave the wrong command. I meant `journalctl -b -1 -u init.scope`. It won't show any *more* messages, just narrow them down.  I think unit failures should already show in red. So unless you're colorblind I guess there's no reason to re-check. (Some types of job failures won't show up in `systemctl --failed`, but they would have shown in the log.  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/10433)

Comment: @TuyenPham So, sorry to pester you, but can you please confirm the unwanted messages during shutdown are from systemd, by showing what they look like? If you have a camera/phone you can just take a picture of it. Either way, make sure to @ me so I get notified :-). (You get notified automatically, because it's your question)

Comment: Likely JdeBP read your question better than I did, and you mean the one message that comes from the Linux kernel e.g. [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/reboot.c?h=v4.19#n241), not from systemd.

Comment: @sourcejedi: udpated post, messing around or customize kernel is not the way I expect, It bring huge effort to maintain kernel after that.

Comment: @JdeBP: Thank for the link, the use-case here I don't have any clue to trace this issue, so try everything suggested to narrow it down is the way, if `systemd` control those message then come to it, if `kernel` itself controls the the message then we have to look what kind of `processes` or `services` causing echo the mesg.  From user perspective I try to understand the issue also improve my knowledges.

Comment: @TuyenPham please, in some way, edit the question to show what the message(s) are that you see and want to disable. Your question is still ambiguous to me.